# How to show interstitial ad when navigating back to the main fragment in bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob, bottomnavigationview

i have four fragments Home, Warning, Donate, and About, Home is the first one shown on launch, what i need is that when users are on any of these fragments (Donate, About, and Caution), and when they go back to the Home fragment using backstack only, I want to show an interstitial ad before showing the home fragment.
I don't want to show the ad when the home fragment launch for first time

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    Deque<Integer> integerDeque = new ArrayDeque<>(3);
    boolean flag = true;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        integerDeque.push(R.id.home_icon);
        loadFragments(new Home_Fragment());
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home_icon);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                item -> {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    if (integerDeque.contains(id)) {
                        if (id == R.id.home_icon) {
                            integerDeque.size();
                            if (flag) {
                                integerDeque.addFirst(R.id.home_icon);
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        }
                        integerDeque.remove(id);
                    }
                    integerDeque.push(id);
                    loadFragments(getFragment(item.getItemId()));
                    return true;
                }
        );

    }

    @SuppressLint("NonConstantResourceId")
    private Fragment getFragment(int itemId) {
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.home_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
                return new Home_Fragment();
            case R.id.guide_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setChecked(true);
                return new Cuation_Fragment();
            case R.id.donate_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(2).setChecked(true);
                return new Donate_Fragment();
            case R.id.about_icon:
                bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setChecked(true);
                return new About_Fragment();
        }
        bottomNavigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
        return new Home_Fragment();
    }

    public void loadFragments(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        integerDeque.pop();
        if (!integerDeque.isEmpty()) {
            bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(integerDeque.peek());
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to give you an idea, you can override the back key press functionality. So, in this case, you define to show your ad whenever the back key is pressed. another way can be showing your ad on home fragment resume life cycle with a condition. This condition is set to true if it is the first time or the back key is pressed; otherwise, it is false and won't show the ad.

Comment: okay but can you give some code reference too , if possible